# How to fix the 'This code is unreachable' error in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, unreachable-code

```py
while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

ball.x += ball_speed_x #This line is unreachable

ball.y += ball_speed_y
```

It doesn't matter what I type in that line, everything is unreachable. How to fix it?

Comment: Oh wait i see now that not the whole 'code' is displayed as code. The code is til ball.y += ball_speed_y

Comment: The first few lines are wrapped inside a while-true block, which will repeatedly execute forever. `ball.x += ...` is indeed unreachable, but without knowing your design and intent we can't give an exact answer. I would guess that you would want it to be indented so it's inside the while-true block, based on the info I know.

Comment: hey @nanofarad thx for your answer! I can send you the whole code if you want!

Comment: I currently don't have time to review the whole set of code (just writing up some comments while on a lunch break at work) -- please give my suggestion a try and see if it works, and if not, try to explain further details by [edit]ing your post.

Comment: i didnt read it good enough. ty for helping you solved my problem!